# Check whether a zip file is protected by password in Objective-C/iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, zip, unzip

I'm using lib [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) to unzip file on iPhone, it works pretty well, however I met a issue about checking if a zip file is protected by password.

I'm wondering if there's a function to check whether a zip file is protected by password before unzipping, but I didn't get lucky to find an api for that. So does anyone who know how to check it in Objective-C/iPhone or any API in [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) I can use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can check central directory in archive, and see if encryption bit is set there.
However, you will need to read some documentation regarding zip file format.

Comment: Thank you, Nick. I read the zip format document on wikipedia, "General purpose bit flag" of ZIP central directory file header is used to indicate if a file is protected by password.

I used a hex editor to open a encryption zip file, I found some of encryption bit has been set to 0, but some of them are set to 1; Also checked on non-encryption zip file, all of encryption bits are set to 0. I don't understand why, could you please help explain that?

Thanks in advance.